# How to add a KML from Google Map to OpenLayers2?

Tags: openlayers-2, google-maps, kml

I would like to add this [KML-link](https://maps.google.de/maps/ms?authuser=0&vps=2&hl=de&ie=UTF8&msa=0&output=kml&msid=203149634091768565111.0004cf65c9b03cc8ae76c) from Google Maps to an OpenLayers `Layer` instance.

The following code is not working:

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.GML("KML", 
    "https://maps.google.de/maps/ms?authuser=0&  
      vps=2&hl=de&
      ie=UTF8&
      msa=0&
      output=kml&
      msid=203149634091768565111.0004cf65c9b03cc8ae76c", 
      {
        format: OpenLayers.Format.KML,
        formatOptions: {
          'extractStyles': true
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should put the kml on the server and link to the file. Like this:

```
var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.GML("KML", "kml/lines.kml", {
   format: OpenLayers.Format.KML
})
map.addLayer(layer);
```